# Does the preimage of the Slodowy slice in $T^*G/P$ have a name?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, slodowy-slice, cotangent-bundles

Let $G$ be your favorite simple complex Lie group, and $P\subset G$ your favorite parabolic subgroup.  We can identify $T^*G/P$ with the space of pairs $$\{(gP,x)\in G/P\times \mathfrak g | x\perp  \operatorname{Ad}_g(\mathfrak p)\}$$ where $\perp$ denotes perpendicularity in the Killing form.  Thus, we have the second projection $p_2:T^*G/P\to \mathfrak g$; when $P=B$, this is the famous Springer map.

Now, let $e$ be your favorite nilpotent in $\mathfrak g$, and let $e,h,f$ be a completion of this to a $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ triple (which exists by Jacobson-Morozov).  Then $S=e+\ker(\operatorname{ad}_f)\subset \mathfrak g$ is an affine subspace of $\mathfrak g$ transverse to the orbit $G\cdot e$ called the **Slodowy slice** to $e$.

It's a theorem that $p_2^{-1}(S)$ is a smooth symplectic variety (it's actually a symplectic reduction of $T^*G/P$ by the action of a nilpotent subgroup $M\subset G$ at a regular value of the moment map), and it's one that I like very much.

> Does this variety have an agreed-upon name?

Comment: Does your question make sense with suitable modifications over an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic?   Slodowy slices often come up in characteristic `$p$` in work by Premet and others.  Also, a small nitpick if someone's favorite nilpotent is the zero element; this is the (usually trivial) case where Jacobson-Morosov doesn't apply.      

Comment: This should all work over any field where $P$ and $e$ are defined, though maybe I'm missing something silly.  As for the case of the 0 nilpotent, if you take f to be 0, then everything works, and e=h=f=0 satisfy the Chevalley relations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Answer (score 2):

In my paper "[Singular blocks of parabolic category O and finite W-algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1860)", these are called "S3-varieties."  S3 is for "Slodowy-Springer-Spaltenstein."

Comment: So, I guess you can accept this answer as soon as someone else starts calling them S3-varieties as well.  It's amazing you wrote an entire paper just for the possibility of extra MO reputation.

Comment: And since intent can be difficult to judge on the internet, let me say that my comment above should not be taken seriously.

Comment: This could be confused with Serre's S3 condition in commutative algebra.

Comment: That's true.  Serre, Springer, Spaltenstein and Steinberg really should have thought of that.